# Execute observer once model loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i am trying to have an observer execute when a model is loaded

```
    sortAttachments:function(){
     console.log('sorting')
     var attachments = this.get('model').get('attachments');
     for(var i = 0;i<attachments.length;i++){
       var a = attachments[i];
       if(a.type=="Link"){
         links.push(a)
       }
     }
   }.observes('models.attachments.@each.type'),
```

the method is currently being called twice, if i change the observes statement to

```
observes('blablabla'),
```

it also gets called twice.

the method must only execute when the attachments property of the model updates

the model code :

```
 App.Card = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  left: DS.attr('number'),
  top: DS.attr('number'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
  attachments: DS.hasMany('attachment',{async:true}),
  tags:DS.hasMany('tag',{async:true})
});
```

Comment: where does that sortAttachments live?  Is it on a controller that's being built twice?

Comment: it lives in a controller, in theory the controller should only have been built once, unless something strange is happening

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't calling sortAttachments?  or trying to get it, because it shouldn't ever get called if it's observing blablabla  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eZexuHUq/1/edit

Comment: ye it was being called by something external. but do you have any idea how i can bind the observer to the attachments property of my model, im using emberdata for all server communications

Comment: Sometimes Ember.ObjectController triggers the observers, when no change is made directlly in the property, like this https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3676

Comment: But in your case I think that the observer trigger several times because the data is fetched in the relationship attachments.

Comment: Woha, that's a weird thing... Good to know, thanks.

Comment: So it only applies if it's an object controller then.

Comment: Additionally your observes is wrong, you're observing `models` instead of `model`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can observe the state of the model using the current state

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  timesFired: 0,

  watcher: function(){
    if(this.get('model.currentState.stateName') == 'root.loaded.saved'){
      this.incrementProperty('timesFired');
    }
  }.observes('model.currentState.stateName')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/aYIkAcUk/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

I think that your observer is called multiple times because for each item loaded in `attachments` relationship, the `model.attachments.@each.type` is triggered. You can use [Ember.run.once](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_once) to collapse all these calls in a single one:

```
  sortAttachments:function(){
     console.log('sorting')
     var attachments = this.get('model').get('attachments');
     for(var i = 0;i<attachments.length;i++){
       var a = attachments[i];
       if(a.type=="Link"){
         links.push(a)
       }
     }
  },
  sortAttachmentsOnce: function() {
    Ember.run.once(this, this.sortAttachments);
  }.observes('model.attachments.@each.type'),
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Just as an FYI, this would only guarantee it would run once if both of the calls happened in the same run loop.

Comment: Yes. I hope that this happen in the same run loop.